# Easy way to copy multiline text to the clipboard?

Tags: iphone, copy, uipasteboard

How hard is it to do? I have a text with about 600 characters, multiple lines. Now I want to copy that text to the clipboard using the UIPasteboard classes. What would I need to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call:

```
// To copy the string myText to the pasteboard:
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setString:myText];
```